# Ruby Array parsing (REGEX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, arrays

I have an array in ruby which has values as below:

```
arr

Value 1 : tb-5-atf, ac-23 
Value 2 : tb-5-atf, ac-5498
Value 3 : tb-5-atf, ac-236
```

I want to extract only the numbers after the last '-' i.e. 23, 5498, 236 out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is very simple you should have googled a bit about ruby strings. However you will need something like this

```
arr[i].split("-").last.to_i
```

I tried this on irb

```
1.9.3p194 :003 > "tb-5-atf, ac-23".split("-").last.to_i
=> 23
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.map {|el| el.split('-').last}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm lazy:

```
[
  'Value 1 : tb-5-atf, ac-23',
  'Value 2 : tb-5-atf, ac-5498',
  'Value 3 : tb-5-atf, ac-236'
].map{ |r| r[/-(\d+)$/, 1] }
```

Which returns:

```
[
    [0] "23",
    [1] "5498",
    [2] "236"
]
```

If you want the integer values:

```
[
  'Value 1 : tb-5-atf, ac-23',
  'Value 2 : tb-5-atf, ac-5498',
  'Value 3 : tb-5-atf, ac-236'
].map{ |r| r[/-(\d+)$/, 1].to_i }
```

Returning:

```
[
    [0] 23,
    [1] 5498,
    [2] 236
]
```

While it's possible to do this using `split('-')` or `scan`, doing so generates temporary arrays, then throws them away, wasting CPU cycles or results in code that isn't straightforward as it tries to unravel the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
a = [["tb-5-atf", "ac-23"],["tb-5-atf", "ac-5498"], ["tb-5-atf", "ac-236"] ]

r = a.map { |i|  i.last.split("-").last.to_i }
p r # output => [23, 5498, 236]
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it amusing to do it this way:

```
arr.map{|v| v.reverse.to_i.to_s.reverse.to_i}
```

(Don't use this in production, it's just another way of thinking about it.)